# Android App - using multidex and firebase - app crashes

Tags: firebase, android-multidex

In my app I'm using a barcode reader from play-services-vision. Because of added firebase messages dependencies, I had to add multidex suppport. But as soon as I add the firebase dependencies, the app crashes on my Galaxy S8 (Andriod 9). When I run the app and like to start the barcode functionality, the ap crashes with a class not found exception:

I did the steps to add multidex and firebase dependency adding step by step, as soon as I add firebase dependency - the crash occurs in the app.

exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: info....app, PID: 15574
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzsb;
        at com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.internal.client.zzd.zzchw(Unknown Source:13)
        at com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.internal.client.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source:20)
        at com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetector$Builder.build(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader.BarcodeCaptureActivity.createCameraSource(BarcodeCaptureActivity.java:184)
        at com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader.BarcodeCaptureActivity.onCreate(BarcodeCaptureActivity.java:105)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7327)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7318)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3094)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsb" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/info....app-wZywn7WMb4zo51Qz3E_qpg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/info....app-wZywn7WMb4zo51Qz3E_qpg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.internal.client.zzd.zzchw(Unknown Source:13) 
        at com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.internal.client.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source:20) 
        at com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetector$Builder.build(Unknown Source:6) 
        at com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader.BarcodeCaptureActivity.createCameraSource(BarcodeCaptureActivity.java:184) 
        at com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader.BarcodeCaptureActivity.onCreate(BarcodeCaptureActivity.java:105) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7327) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7318) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3094) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

build.gradle excerpt:

```
 compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "info....app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 101
        versionName "1.0.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.configrelease
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    // Important - the CameraSource implementation in this project requires version 8.1 or higher.
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.4.0+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    // firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.0.4'
}
```

Comment: Have you tried  updating the dependency to latest version?
like
 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:19.1.5'

 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.1'